# Relative Homotopy (for spaces)

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I have learnt the notion of relative homotopy for maps (https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Homotopy/Relative).

Is there a corresponding notion for spaces? E.g. Is there such thing as a space $X$ homotopy equivalent to a space $Y$ relative to $A\subseteq X\cap Y$? Thanks for pointing to me to any reference.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, you could make this work in [the category of topological pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_pair). Also there seem to be some kind of relation between the relative homotopy from $(X, A)$ and the classical homotopy from $X/ A$. Aren't these two equivalent? Probably you need some additional assumptions on $X$ and/or $A$.

Comment: @freakish Thanks! Is this something new or established theory?

Comment: Well, this is definitely well established for pointed spaces (i.e. when $A$ is a singleton), have a look at the fundamental group. There are some results for more general $A$. Have a look at Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology", there are some results when $(X,A)$ is a CW-pair. But generally (withouty any assumptions on $(X,A)$) I don't think that there's a lot of research done in this topic.

Comment: The generalisation, replacing a subspace inclusion $A\hookrightarrow X$ with an arbitrary map $f:A\rightarrow X$ is well understood, if a little too difficult to work with in practice. It is simply the notion of homotopy in the category of morphisms of a suitable homotopic category. Likewise you can fix $A$ and do homotopy in the category of spaces under $A$. See Strom's "Modern Classical Homotopy" sections 4.7, 5.5 for some easily accessible material.